# Why is @PropertySource not used when application.properties is present?

Tags: java, spring, properties, mapping

The situation I'm in requires a file with some properties (eventually containing a list of ID's and Email addresses) to be mapped to a HashMap. In Spring I found that a properties file can be mapped to an object with `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@PropertySource`. To test this mechanism, I created a test project, but `@PropertySource` seems to be ignored when default `application.properties` file exists. I'm wondering how this is possible and how I can solve it so that it uses the properties file specified.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DemoProperties.java**

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class DemoProperties {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**test.properties**

```
test.name=myNameGood
```

**application.properties**

```
test.name=myNameBad
```

**ApplicationTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    DemoProperties demoProperties;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(demoProperties.getName());
    }

}
```

So this Test prints `myNameBad` when `application.properties` is present, but when I delete or rename that file, the output is `myNameGood` (which is desired).

Comment: it is not ignored. It is overwritten. If you have the same property in both, the one in application.properties has higher priority. try adding variable with different name and check

Comment: @pvpkiran changing the variable works, but I still don't understand why it is overwritten in my example. What is the point of specifying the property source then?

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` only works for properties loaded by Spring boot i.e. in properties coming from the default `application.properties` and friends. It doesn't work for properties loaded with `@PropertySource` those are loaded later in the proces and the `@ConfigurationProperties` are bound before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties coming from the default locations (here `application.properties)` has higher priority as custom properties used in a class.

From the Spring Boot documentation :

> [72.3 Change the location of external properties of an application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties)
>
> A nice way to augment and modify this is to add @PropertySource
>   annotations to your application sources. Classes passed to the
>   SpringApplication static convenience methods, and those added using
>   setSources() are inspected to see if they have @PropertySources, and
>   if they do, those properties are added to the Environment early enough
>   to be used in all phases of the ApplicationContext lifecycle.
>   **Properties added in this way have lower priority than any added using
>   the default locations (e.g. application.properties), system
>   properties, environment variables or the command line.**

And this priority makes sense as configuration that you can provide at the runtime (such as `application.properties`) should always be able to override configuration "hardcoded" in the application.

---

> To test this mechanism, I created a test project,

To test a class or a behavior, you should rather write a unit test.
You could so use one of these way to override `application.properties` values:

- Renaming `test.properties` into `application.properties` and moving it into `src/test/resources`.
- using [`@TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html). From the javadoc :

> Test property sources have higher precedence than those loaded from
>   the operating system's environment or Java system properties as well
>   as property sources added by the application declaratively via
>   @PropertySource or programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, stupid that I haven't thought about that. Do you have any recommendations for a solution?